# Cucumber: Multiple tags giving 0 scenarios and 0 steps

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have multiple cucumber feature files with different tags, and in my package.json I specify all tags with `and` but it giving me 0 scenarios and 0 steps, any thoughts/idea on what I'm missing ?

```
 "scripts": {
    "atdd:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --format json:cucumber.json --tags='@putLockDev and @getLockDev and @dev'"
  }
```

0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.002s (executing steps: 0m00.000s)

Comment: Do you have a scenario tagged with all 3 tags?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do `--tags='@putLockDev or @getLockDev or @dev'` unless you have a scenario tagged with all three tags

Remember that the [tag expressions](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=javascript#tags) are `and`, `not` and `or`, and the `and` is inclusive of previous tags

The `or` expression however will run tests tagged with either